# Why is my geth node stuck on block 7130891?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, geth-debugging, forks, blockchain-fork

My `geth` mainnet node (version 1.8.21) has stopped on block 7130891.

Interestingly, `eth.syncing` returns false and `eth.blockNumber` constantly returns 7130891. It was working up until ~24 hours ago.

Has my node forked? If so, how did it do this (so I can avoid it in the future)? How do I resync it on the main chain?

Comment: Check if you have any peers with `admin.peers`. Try restarting geth, if you have a peer enode you can add peers with `admin.addPeer` from geth console.

Comment: `admin.peers` returns 25. I restarted `geth` and it seems to be syncing nominally now. I will see what happens when it either syncs or gets stuck again.